# Is it possible to create a pointer to an inherited class by incrementing a base class pointer(C++)?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

Based on what I’ve read, it seems the memory for derived objects is made sequentially with the base class and all its data made first and then immediately followed by the following classes down the inheritance tree. So if I make a base class pointer that is equal to a new derived class object, and then increment it by one(which will actually add the size of the base class to the address), then will I arrive at the derived class? If so, can I then access the derived class’s data in this way?

Comment: No, you cannot do that.

Comment: There are some very special cases where address of base class is equal to the address of derived class, but it will never be validly accessible with `&base + 1`. In general you should use a proper cast (`static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`)

Comment: *"will I arrive at the derived class?"* -- I'd give this a "no" on a technicality. The base class is part of the derived class. So you started at the derived class. You cannot "arrive" at a place where you already are.

Comment: No.  The offset between base and derived class is both implementation-specific and depends on nature of both classes (e.g. how many bases does the derived class have) - so may vary between cases.    If you want to obtain a pointer to a derived class from a pointer to a base class, use what the language provides.  An implicit conversion is possible if the inheritance is `public` (and in some other cases).  Failing that, an explicit conversion (e.g. `_cast` operators) may work [albeit, there are limitations on that].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and no. In the very simplest case it will work in most cases:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
int v;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   int b;
};

int main() {
   Derived d;
   Base* p = &d;
   p++;

   // these will match on all compilers I'm aware of
   printf("%p %p\n", p, &d.b);
   return 0;
}
```

For single inheritance, that is typically what you'll see from most compilers *(although I'd be very worried actually relying on that in production code!)*

However, sadly things aren't always that simple! In C++ we often have multiple inheritance, virtual inheritance, abstract base classes and all those bits of goodness. So here is a scenario where it would absolutely not work!

```cpp
struct Animal {
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
    virtual void Eat() {}
    int a;

};

struct Mammal: Animal {
    virtual void Breathe() {}
    int b;
};

struct WingedAnimal: Animal {
    virtual void Flap() {}
    int c;
};

// A bat is a winged mammal
struct Bat: Mammal, WingedAnimal {
    int d;
};
```

There are however far safer approaches to handling upcasting (e.g. dynamic_cast, or your own RTTI system). You probably will want to be using those :)

Comment: Alright I think I’m understanding. So basically incrementing it will indeed move it to the address of the derived class. But that address can’t be leveraged in any meaningful way? Like what if you de-referenced p in after that increment in your first example? Would it just crash? Thank you for all you’ve written so far by the way

Comment: ```*((int*)p) = 42```; I mean, you could cast p to an int pointer, dereference, and assign a value (which would assign to d.b). However, doing so would be considered bad practice!